# jquery tree plugin expanding items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some html that looks like this:

```
<div class="list-group">
    <a id="427" href="#" class="list-group-item"><i class="fa indent0 fa-caret-down"></i>Home</a>
    <a id="428" href="#" class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-caret-right indent1"></i>Images</a>
    <a id="429" href="#" class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-caret-right indent1"></i>Videos</a>
    <a id="430" href="#" class="list-group-item"><i class="fa indent1 fa-caret-right"></i>Documents</a>
    <a id="431" href="#" class="list-group-item" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-caret-right indent2"></i>Sub category</a>
    <a id="432" href="#" class="list-group-item" style="display: none;"><i class="fa indent2 fa-caret-down"></i>Another sub</a>
    <a id="433" href="#" class="list-group-item" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-caret-right indent3"></i>Super sub</a>
    <a id="434" href="#" class="list-group-item" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-caret-right indent2"></i>asdfasdf</a>
    <a id="435" href="#" class="list-group-item" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-caret-right indent2"></i>asdf</a>
    <a id="436" href="#" class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-caret-right indent1"></i>Audio</a>
</div>
```

when I click the **.fa** I want it to get the **indent** plus 1 between itself and the next item with the same indent class to unhide.
So in this case,

if we press on id **430**, it will show 431, 432, 434 and 435.

Now, that is the easy part. What I need it to also do, is check of any element between **430** and **436** (in this case) and if any of the elements have the class **fa-caret-down** then it shows the children of that too.

Currently I have made this into a plugin and my code actually works, but I think it could be a lot neater.
I am hoping that some of your gurus will see a simpler solution.

Here is my solution currently:

```
events: function () {
    var self = this;

    $(self.element).on("click", ".fa", function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();

        var $target = $(this);
        var indent = $target.prop('className').match(/\b(indent\d+)\b/)[1];

        if ($target.hasClass("fa-caret-right")) {
            $target.removeClass("fa-caret-right").addClass("fa-caret-down");
            self.showChildren($target.parent(), indent);

            if (typeof self.options.onItemExpand === "function") {
                self.options.onItemExpand.apply(this, arguments);
            }
        } else {
            var $children = $target.parent().nextUntil("a:has(." + indent + ")");

            $target.removeClass("fa-caret-down").addClass("fa-caret-right");
            $children.hide();

            if (typeof self.options.onItemContract === "function") {
                self.options.onItemContract.apply(this, arguments);
            }
        }
    })
},
showChildren: function ($target, className) {
    var self = this;
    var num = parseInt(className.match(/(\d+)$/)[1], 10);
    var $children = $target.nextUntil("a:not(:has(.indent" + (num + 1) + "))");

    $.each($children, function (i, item) {
        var $item = $(this).find(".fa");
        if ($item.hasClass("fa-caret-down")) {
            var indent = $item.prop('className').match(/\b(indent\d+)\b/)[1];
            self.showChildren($(this), indent);
        }
    });

    $children.show();
}
```

My solution nearly works (although I hope someone can make it neater) but there is an issue.
If you click **Home** it will hide all (as expected) but if you click to show again, it will show all but **Audio**. The same thing happens if you expand down to **Documents > Another sub > Super sub** and expand that. When you contract it, **Audio** will vanish.

http://jsfiddle.net/sn92W/

I assume this is to do with **nextUntil**.

Please help :)

Comment: I feel like this would be easier if you used nested list items, instead of having to declare an indent class. This is an interesting problem though. Good luck :)

Comment: I agree with you, but unfortunately, this is a limitation due to using bootstrap. For list-groups with links, they change from UL to Div with anchors. Not really sure why :)